# how to improve TensorFlow object detection model?

Tags: neural-network, captcha, object-detection

I need to diagnosis captcha for a project. I did this using the object_detection provided by Tensorflow.

also, I added 500 captcha samples by turning images into **XML** by LabelImg and then to TFRecord.

> beside I used `"faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28"`

The problem is that the accuracy of the machine is very low.

My questions are:

**Can the problem be solved by increasing the number of training data?**

**Should I change my algorithm?**

**How effective is the use of the Yolo 3 instead of the detection object provided by Tensorflow?**

Comment: Yolo is probably going to be more efficient than Tensorflow's builtin detection. Yolo 3 is one of the best methods of object detection, so I doubt it would be less accurate than Tensorflow. A hitch is you would need to interface with C to use Yolo (although someone probably wrote a wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

**Q.** Can the problem be solved by increasing the number of training data?

**A.** It would be depend on how many data you can get more. I think that only increasing the number of training data is not good approach.

Consider using Fine-tuning existing trained model to detect object class. If you want to fine-tune the model, you need to be careful class label assignment because existing trained model like YOLO3, Faster RCNN, etc. has no label "captcha" in their training dataset.

I recommend you to refer to [this website](https://medium.com/deepquestai/train-object-detection-ai-with-6-lines-of-code-6d087063f6ff) that can help you to fine-tune the model.

**Q.** Should I change my algorithm?

**A.** Do as you wish.

**Q.** How effective is the use of the Yolo 3 instead of the detection object provided by Tensorflow?

**A.** In my opinion, two different models are much the same if you don't need to consider inference time.